# Upload archive AWS Glacier Python Scripting

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to make a python script that allows me to create / delete/list vaults, execute jobs, list / describe vault jobs, upload/download archives, and make and get inventories.

I'm  using `awscli` and `boto3` python3 packages

I'm facing something quiet weird, when uploading a file with command line as it follows :

`aws glacier upload-archive --vault-name <vault_name> --archive-description <archive_name> --body <file_2_upload> --account-id -`

Where `vault_name`, `archive_name`, `file_2_upload` are variables passed when executing the script and `account-id` is set up before script execution with `aws configure` command

It takes a while in function of the file size, but it works as expected

When trying with my script (this is the part that is in charge of backups)

`glacier = boto3.client('glacier')
upload = glacier.upload_archive(vaultName=vault, body=archive, archiveDescription=name)`

The answer is almost immediate, and the output shows something like this

`HTTP Code : 201` ==> which means operation successful

However my vault size doesn't increase, and I cannot find the file in it

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've finally found the reason why it was not working, I needed to charge the file / filepart in memory as it follows :

```
with open(archive, 'rb') as upload:
    archive_upload = upload.read(size)
    glacier_upload = glacier.upload_archive(vaultName=vault, archiveDescription=name, body=archive_upload)
```

I hope that it can helps anyone facing the same issue

Cheers

Comment: what does "charge the file in memory" mean? what is the "size" in read() function?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I meant loads the file in memory

Comment: Finally I've added a method that read file chunks of 32 Mb, and problem is solved